# computing the "mix effect" in the evolution of a variable on R

Tags: r, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics

**Background:**
I am currently working on a dataset representing the evolution of the income of a hospital which hosts several medical specialties.

The ratio income/medical act increases between year $N$ and year $N_1$.

I would like to compute the part that is to be imputed to the change in the activity mix (that is, the fact a specialty A, between year N and year N1, sees its number of medical acts increase more than a specialty B : the specialty A having a greater ratio income/medical act since the beginning (year N) for example, this change in the repartition of medical acts between two specialties may explain the overall increase in the variable income/medical act), and the part which is to be imputed to the raise of tariffs (income/act in each specialty : meaning, if the repartition of acts between specialties stays the same between year N and year N1, the raise in income/act in each specialty explains totally the overall income/act).

Ideally, after having been able to compute it, I would like to plot it (a stacked bar plot probably does the trick, although I would welcome any suggestion and am quite fond of 4 quadrant bubble plots, as is done on excel).

For reproducibility, here is the structure of my dataset (I only kept the three first rows to make it simpler here) :

```
 structure(list(specialty = c("chirurgy", "cardiology", "pediatry"
 ), income_N = c(137827, 76293, 588383), income_N1 = c(338782, 
 33987, 386936), nb_of_acts_N = c(67389, 37847, 87392), nb_of_acts_N1 = c(83673, 
 37383, 73693)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the beginning of my code:

```
 # computing the change in income/act 

 library(janitor)
 library(dplyr)

 df <- df %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>%
  mutate(income_per_act_N = income_N/nb_of_acts_N,
         income_per_act_N1 = income_N1/nb_of_acts_N1) %>%
  group_by(specialty)%>%
  mutate(evolution_income_per_act = (income_per_act_N1- 
  income_per_act_N)/income_per_act_N*100)

df$evolution_income_per_act = paste(round(df$evolution_income_per_act, digits = 2), "%")
```

**Problem:**
How do I start my analysis?  How do I relate "mix effect" vs. the pure "price effect" and "pure volume"?  Is there an interaction between mix, price, and volume?  How do I account for that?

Can you point me to the first steps in regression that would allow me to account for these things?

Comment: I think they are looking at stats-relevant content.  I think this might be an analog to metallurgy, where you are looking at ratios of alloying compounds and trying to find the one that makes for the best strength.  It is compounded with economics (supply, demand, price), and many of the approaches to ask and answer answer questions there require stats.

Comment: yes, exactly, and on stack overflow i was told to post it here...

Comment: I think it goes here, and whomever voted it for a different forum might not have taken much time to understand the question.  There are some unpleasant folks (or algorithms) who do that.  Can you give "toy" data so that if I have code in the answer, you can use it more easily on your actual stuff?